# SwiftUI Coreml: Failed to get the home directory when checking model path

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, coreml, createml

I was doing this [tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/connecting-swiftui-to-core-ml). However even though I did everything according to the video, when I build and click the button, I get this error:
Failed to get the home directory when checking model path.
I checked that code and project files but I don't know how to fix this issue.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var wakeUp = Date.now
    @State private var sleepAmount = 8.0
    @State private var coffeeAmount = 1
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack{
                Text("When do you want to wake up?")
                    .font(.headline)
                DatePicker("Please enter a time", selection: $wakeUp, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                    .labelsHidden()
                Text("Desired amount of sleep")
                    .font(.headline)
                Stepper("\(sleepAmount.formatted()) hours", value: $sleepAmount, in: 4...12, step: 0.25)
                Text("Daily coffee intake")
                    .font(.headline)
                Stepper(coffeeAmount == 1 ? "1 cup" : "\(coffeeAmount) cups", value: $coffeeAmount, in: 1...20)
            }
            .navigationTitle("BetterRest")
            .toolbar{
                Button("Calculate", action: calculateBedTime)
            }
            .alert(alertTitle, isPresented: $showingAlert){
                Button("OK"){
                    
                }
            } message: {
                Text(alertMessage)
            }
        }
    }
    func calculateBedTime(){
        do{
            let config = MLModelConfiguration()
            let model = try SleepCalculator(configuration: config)
            let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: wakeUp)
            let hour = (components.hour ?? 0) * 60 * 60
            let minute = (components.minute ?? 0) * 60
            let prediction = try model.prediction(wake:Int64(hour + minute), estimatedSleep: sleepAmount, coffee: Int64(coffeeAmount))
            let sleepTime = wakeUp - prediction.actualSleep
            alertTitle = "Your ideal bedtime is ..."
            alertMessage = sleepTime.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
        }
        catch{
            alertTitle = "Sorry, there was a problem about calculating your bedtime."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are _sure_ that the directory is correct, try using `let model = try SleepCalculator()` instead. Let me know if that works.

Comment: `...Failed to get the home directory when checking model path`, but you don't show the code for how you check the home directory 
and you don't show the code for the model path you use, presumably in `SleepCalculator`. It seems to be relevant to answer the question.
Is this a Playground app?